# excel vba download text file from the internet that update every 5 minutes

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to download a file from this link:
https://www.hko.gov.hk/tide/marine/data/ALL.txt

This file updates itself every 5 minutes. So I went on and create an excel VBA and then use a scheduler to activate this excel file every 5 minutes. Yet somehow for some strange reason, the file I downloaded in the computer did not update every 5 minutes. The content stays the same and is different from the text file if I use chrome or IE to open.

Below is a very typical script I copied from the internet.

```
Function DownloadFile(link As String)
Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", link, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\raw\" & "temp.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Side note: the above should likely be a sub. You don't need the username and password parameters and this line: myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody can be removed. And all your variables should be declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be caching. Try the following where a requestHeader is added to try and mitigate for potential caching. The other common alternative, adding a random number to the end of the URL doesn't seem to work for this site.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 3
        DownloadFile "https://www.hko.gov.hk/tide/marine/data/ALL.txt"
        Debug.Print Now
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 5, 0)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub DownloadFile(ByVal link As String)
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object, oStream  As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    With WinHttpReq
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send

        Debug.Print StrConv(.responsebody, vbUnicode)

        If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
            Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            oStream.Open
            oStream.Type = 1
            oStream.Write .responsebody
            oStream.SaveToFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\raw\" & "temp.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
            oStream.Close
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @QHarr Excellent. Is there a way to use excel during the execution of waiting? I tried DoEvents but seems not to work for me.

Comment: @YasserKhalil   hi - what do you mean?

Comment: @QHarr I mean during the waiting, excel is frozen and I am wondering if it is possible to make excel available for using during the execution and the wait time

Comment: @YasserKhalil  DoEvents is the usual way. Also, found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/4sc3ig/allow_user_interaction_with_your_spreadsheet_mid/

Comment: But Excel is still frozen although I used it. I think `Application.Wait` part is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

QHarr's answer did not work for me. I tried many solutions, but it seems either they did not work with VBA or there was a need for an early binding call, which I did not like so I came up with the following method. Simply, we will try to **delete the same url/file from the cache** and then proceed into downloading the file:

```
'--- copy this to the top of the module (below Option Explicit) ---
'Declaration for deleting a file from the cache:
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "wininet.dll" Alias _
    "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" (ByVal lpszUrlName As String) As Long
```

The function should be modified as follows:

```
Function DownloadFile(link As String)
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    
    'First delete the file from cache:
    'On Error Resume Next
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry url
    
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", link, False, "username", "password"
    WinHttpReq.send
    
    myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\raw\" & "temp.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If

End Function
```